# How to Solve eror in unluac like the file not have a signature of valid lua file

Tags: lua

i try decrypt LuaT in unluac and i got eror "the input file not have a signature of valid lua file"

i try again in different file but same

Comment: guess it's not a valid lua file

Comment: Upload your file to let us see if it is indeed a Lua bytecode file.  Or maybe unluac still does not support Lua 5.4 (LuaT is the signature of Lua 5.4 bytecode)

Comment: This is the message when unluac doesn't detect the correct 4 byte signature at the start of the file -- for all Lua versions this is (hex) 1b 4c 75 61. 4c 75 61 is "Lua" in ASCII (and, yes, the following "T" would be (hex) 54 meaning Lua 5.4 which unluac supports). The 1b (ASCII "escape"/"ESC" character) needs to be there. I can probably give you better support on the unluac forum (especially if you can provide the file in question).

Comment: [link](https://rentry.co/gasmas)

Comment: this the file sir